# Console showing aborted for requests to CDN scripts in IE debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do some jQuery edit/update from front-end which is NOT working in IE but working in all other browsers. The strange thing is that the jQuery is in an 'aborted' state when the page is loaded. Code is as follows:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/EnvInfo/WebRoot/js2/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/EnvInfo/WebRoot/js2/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
```

I have also included the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />`
```

Below is the image for reference

[image: aborted state jquery in IE]

Comment: The request is aborted because the file is already in your cache. This should not affect the running of your code. Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: whenever i do something ...it gives an error 404 for java file not found.. i mean the jquery runs but always with an error while in other browsers it runs fine